# Proving an equation using Fermat's little theorem

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Prove:
$$a^k \pmod p = a^{k \pmod {p-1}} \pmod p$$
for all primes p using Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k=q(p-1)+r$ where $0<r<p-1$. Then $r=k\mod p-1$. But $a^k=(a^{p-1})^q\times a^r$. But Fermat's little theorem tells us that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1~(\mod p)$, which implies $(a^{p-1})^q\equiv 1~(\mod p)$. So $(a^{p-1})^q\times a^r\equiv a^r~(\mod p)$

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, $(a,p)=1$.

Then, $k=(p-1)q+r$ for some $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ (with $0 \leq r < p-1$). Then

$a^{k} = a^{(p-1)q+r} \equiv (a^{p-1})^{q}a^{r} \equiv a^{r} \pmod{p}$

and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it obvious, because $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p?$$